# How to Verify if file exist with VB script

Tags: vbscript

How do I verify via VBScript if the file `conf` exist under Program Files (i.e. C:\Program Files\conf)?

For example if it exists, then `msgBox "File exists"`
If not, then `msgbox "File doesn't exist"`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality in VBS for that, however, you can use the [FileSystemObject FileExists function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23stk5t(v=VS.85).aspx) for that :

```
Option Explicit
DIM fso    
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If (fso.FileExists("C:\Program Files\conf")) Then
  WScript.Echo("File exists!")
  WScript.Quit()
Else
  WScript.Echo("File does not exist!")
End If

WScript.Quit()
```

Comment: The `WScript.Quit` method calls in your example are absolutely unnecessary.